# TextView between two elements

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Android app and I created a view. This view contains RelativeLayout and it contains 3 child elements: CheckBox, TextView and Button. CheckBox is placed at the left parent's side, Button is placed at the right side and TextView between those elements. TextView can contain a text with arbitrary length and if the text is very long, TextView must not overlap neither ChecBox nor Button. Now it looks like this:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

Is it possible to place elements properly?

Comment: Post your layout.xml

Comment: a linearLayout wrapping the 3 views should do the trick. just remember to set the textview's weight to 1 and width to 0

Comment: Use linearlayout instead of relative layout.

Comment: add android:layout_toLeftOf= attribute to your check box

Comment: you can archive that design using **2 elements (checkBox and Button)**

Comment: If my answer helps you then please mark as a right my answer from tick mark otherwise i'm gonna remove this answer brother : https://www.google.com/search?q=right+mark+as+an+answer+stackoverflow&sxsrf=ACYBGNQVsfXj9VeT9WRKWerxeSRoAMe2uQ:1579936139192&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQk-DimJ7nAhWBc30KHdm9CGAQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1517&bih=730#imgrc=9_JN49MpzDykBM:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use this**

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="button" />

    <TextView
        android:text="this is my test this is my test this is my test this is my test this is my test "
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/checkBox"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkBox"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

a linearLayout (instead of relativelayout) wrapping the 3 views should do the trick. just remember to set the textview's weight to 1 and width to 0

```
<LinearLayout  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<CheckBox 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weight="1"  />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Helovusndijfsdufsdjfkjdsbfkjsdkjfbskjdbfkjsbdfkjbskdjfbskjbdfkjbfsdf"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.005"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is how it would look:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loren Emsim Loren Emsim Loren Emsim Loren Emsim Loren Emsim Loren Emsim Loren Emsim Loren Emsim Loren Emsim Loren Emsim Loren Emsim Loren Emsim"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your checkbox & button's gravity is on wrong way.it's not vertically|center

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `weight` to textview it will adjust automatically

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="large text view that not overlay neither checkbox nor button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ConstraintLayout you can get this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="this is a long text bla bla bla la this is a long text bla bla bla la"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Result: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some Long text Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla "
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />    
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

No need to put **Textview** between  **checkBox and Button**,
You can do with 2 elements (CheckBox and Button).
what you have to do
just set the text to **checkbox** then set button.

**For better understanding read below code:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:text="Some bla blablablablablablabla bla bla bla bla bla bla "
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```